# problems with rock paper scissors in python

Tags: python

I am quite literally two weeks familiar with any programming whatsoever. I am currently enrolled in a class on Python. I have a programming assignment that requires me to write a program that simulates the game 'rock, paper, scissors'. It is supposed to be designed as a two player game that:
 1: gets the first player's name.
 2: gets the second player's name.
 3: displays a 'Let's Play!' intro.
 4: asks the first player for their entry.
 5: asks the second player for their entry.
 6: display the results.
 7: ask the user if they want to play again.

I have been able to write the simple programs up to this point, but I am really lost on this assignment; I can't seem to get anything to work at all.

any help on how to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: make sure to clear the screen after the first player enters their selection

Comment: For requirement #7, research `while` loops and infinite loops.

Comment: You should show us what you have so far, or ask specific questions.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  If you are at a complete loss for how to start, SO is probably not the place to ask for help.  To understand why, please read the [faq] and [ask].  You should probably ask your professor for help getting started.

Comment: Begin at the beginning. Can you get the first player's name?

Answer (score 1):

First things first: Don't get overwhelmed by how complicated it sounds! You can definitely handle it. Break it up into chunks that you can manage: first of all, you need to get names. Python 2.7 (I'm assuming you're using 2.7, not 3.x) has a function for getting input from the user, [raw_input()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input). Get the names, and [store them in variables](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings). Finally, print out your introduction.

After this, you're going to be using a loop. This is because the user may want to play again, and you need a way to restart if they choose to. Inside this loop, you'll be doing more of the same: getting and storing input, printing things, and so on. As you can see from the above links, the Python documentation is an valuable resource!

That should be enough to get you started. Now try it out, and report back with what you've done if you encounter any issues. Programming is tricky at first, but you'll quickly get used to it. Don't get discouraged!

Comment: # This is as far as I have been able to go...
# I've been at this all night and I'm getting unbelievably frustrated.

playerOne=input('Player 1: Enter your first name: ')

input(playerOne,'Enter your choice: ')

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\Python Tests\discount.py", line 3, in <module>
#    input(playerOne,'Enter your choice: ')
# TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
>>>

Comment: Edit your question instead of trying to explain it here; comments can't display the kind of formatting you need.

Comment: The first part that you have is great!, but you need to just end it there. Make your first line playerOne = input('Player 1: Enter your first name: ') Now you've successfully recorded the first player's name. Now do the same for the second user, but be sure to store it in a different variable! After that, print out your introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Do pseudo code for defining all the possible outcomes, and conditional statements for saying what happens "if" one has one and the other has their choice.  who wins?  make function modules for each specific process that happens, which is basically just what i already said.  at least that's how i would do it in C, I am very new to programming myself.
Chris